# How can I get Dragonvale notifications?

Tags: dragonvale

I've enabled the Notification Center and badge app icon settings for Dragonvale in the Settings app, and I enabled all notifications inside Dragonvale. However, I get no egg/reminders notifications whatsoever. When my eggs are ready to hatch I get no notification.

Does this setting *work*? Is there something particular I need to enable first? Why am I not getting Egg notifications? I might like the others too, but egg notifications are the most important ones and I've never gotten one. I'm on iOS 5.1 on the current latest version of Dragonvale.

Comment: That's odd... It works for me just fine, and I have all the same settings you have. =(

Comment: works for me as well.

Comment: @Fluttershy you get, specifically, the Egg notifications?

Comment: @BenBrocka Aye. I get notifications showing that the dragon, by name, has finished incubating. Or that my dragons have finished breeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above have said that notifications are working fine for them. They are working for me, also. So it's probably an issue with your phone. The basic troubleshooting is to reset, restart, restore.

- To reset, hold both the home button and the sleep/wake button until the apple logo comes up.

As for restarting and resetting, you should probably know how to do that.

Make sure the notifications are turned on after you reset/restart/restore.

Settings - Notifications- Sort Manually- Dragonvale- Notification Center  [ON]

Comment: It's done this on two iPads, one of which I restored a couple times...

Comment: Fiddling around with the settings (disabling notifications in app/settings, then enabling them again) eventually worked